# Problem in submission, "Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced" without any other error messages

Tags: errors, pdf

I tried to submit Latex file to arXiv

But, it showed only "Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced" error message, and nothing showed.

Here is my log

```
[verbose]: Creating arXiv submission AutoTeX object
[verbose]: *** Using TeX Live 2016 ***
[verbose]: Calling arXiv submission AutoTeX process
[verbose]: TeX/AutoTeX.pm: admin_timeout = minion
[verbose]: <MainText.tex> is of type 'PDFLATEX'.
[verbose]: <SupplementalMaterial.tex> is of type 'PDFLATEX'.
[verbose]: <revsymb4-2.sty> is of type 'TeX auxiliary'.
[verbose]: <MainText.bbl> is of type 'TeX auxiliary'.
[verbose]: <aps4-2.rtx> is of type 'TeX auxiliary'.
[verbose]: <SupplementalMaterial.bbl> is of type 'TeX auxiliary'.
[verbose]: <revtex4-2.cls> is of type 'TeX auxiliary'.
[verbose]: ~~~~~~~~~~~ Processing file 'MainText.tex'
[verbose]: arXiv Warning: user included plain hyperref directive.
[verbose]: TEXMFCNF is unset.
[verbose]: ~~~~~~~~~~~ Running hpdflatex for the first time ~~~~~~~~
[verbose]: Running: "(export HOME=/tmp PATH=/texlive/2016/bin/arch:/bin; cd /submissions/3081000/ && pdflatex 'MainText.tex' < /dev/null)" 2>&1
[verbose]: This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17 (TeX Live 2016) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./MainText.tex
LaTeX2e <2016/03/31> patch level 3
Babel <3.9r> and hyphenation patterns for 83 language(s) loaded.
(./revtex4-2.cls
Document Class: revtex4-2 2019/01/18/14:29:48 4.2c (https://journals.aps.org/re
vtex/ for documentation)
ltxutil[2019/01/18/14:29:48 4.2c utilities package (portions licensed from W. E
. Baxter web at superscript.com)]
ltxfront[2019/01/18/14:29:48 4.2c frontmatter package (AO,DPC,MD)]
ltxgrid[2019/01/18/14:29:48 4.2c page grid package (portions licensed from W. E
. Baxter web at superscript.com)]
(./aps4-2.rtx)

Class revtex4-2 Warning: No journal specified, using default pra.

(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/textcase/textcase.sty)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amssymb.sty
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amsfonts.sty))
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty))
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty))
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-local/tex/latex/natbib/natbib.sty

This is natbib version 8.31
*************************************************************
!!WARNING!! !!WARNING!! !!WARNING!! !!WARNING!!

This version (v8.31) of natbib is stricter in its formatting
requirements for bibitem entries than the previous version
used at arXiv (v7.1).

If your submission encounters a problem see

http://arXiv.org/help/faq/texlive

and the natbib documentation at

http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/natbib/

for explanation and adjust your submission accordingly.
The arXiv team.
*************************************************************

) (./revsymb4-2.sty)
! Undefined control sequence.
\setup@hook ...elsep \let \@listi \@listI \@listi
\set@page@grid \providecom...
l.7590 \setup@hook

?
! Emergency stop.
\setup@hook ...elsep \let \@listi \@listI \@listi
\set@page@grid \providecom...
l.7590 \setup@hook

! ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
Transcript written on MainText.log.

[verbose]: pdflatex 'MainText.tex' failed.
```

Sorry for complex text..

Is there anyone helP?

Comment: You seem to use an rather new revtex.cls with an quite old tex system. That is bound to give problems.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer it's arXivs build system, it is known to be a lot behind. They seem to have their reasons not to upgrade.

Comment: Given that arXiv is known to run old systems, it might be better to use the standard `article` class instead of `revtex` or try to incldue your newer version of revtex.

Comment: @daleif I know but the log looks as if the OP added a newer local version of revtex to the document folder.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer right did not notice that, that may need newer support packages as well, better not to use.

Comment: I agree with the others that it is better not to use newer versions of classes with older systems. However, you might try uploading also `aps10pt4-2.rtx` or the `11pt` or `12pt` versions of this file, that is where `\@listI` is defined.